# Optimize nested SELECT query and do it with ActiveRecord query API

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have this SQL query to select some of my offers and it works as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE region='26'

AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM `modificator_values` WHERE
    `modificator_values`.`offer_id`=`offers`.`id` AND
     (modificator_values.modificator_id = "5") AND (modificator_values.data = "data1")
) 

AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM `modificator_values` WHERE
     `modificator_values`.`offer_id`=`offers`.`id` AND
     (modificator_values.modificator_id = "8") AND (modificator_values.data = "data2")
)
```

Is there a way to optimize it and do it using ActiveRecord query API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not using any API, I suggest you use this trick, you only check for existance in both subqueries and could save that 'double' time by doing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM offers 
WHERE region='26'

AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
    SELECT modificator_id,COUNT(data) 
    FROM modificator_values 
    WHERE
      modificator_values.offer_id=1 AND
       (((modificator_values.modificator_id = "5") AND (modificator_values.data = "data1")) OR
       ((modificator_values.modificator_id = "8") AND (modificator_values.data = "data2")))
    GROUP BY modificator_id 
    ) s
    ) > 1
```

I've tested it on this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE offers 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     region varchar(20)
    );
CREATE TABLE modificator_values 
    (
     modificator_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     data varchar(20), 
     offer_id int
    );

INSERT INTO offers VALUES (1,'26');
INSERT INTO modificator_values VALUES(5,'data1',1);
INSERT INTO modificator_values VALUES(8,'data2',1);
```

Comment: No problem, if you think this answers your question please use the V next to it in order to approve it for future users that might come across it, you can also use the arrow up in order to upvote it and mark it as a useful answer.
and welcome to Stackoverflow =]